# Insert into table when row not exist else update table using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am using Oracle database 12C. I have `VK_ORDER` table which has lot of redundant data with the combination of columns `OID` and `EXID`. The table has column `FILENAME` where the filename is given from which the data are getting inserted in this table and the table has `SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT` column where on which date time the data has inserted. The daily job is running on this table and redundant data of combination `OID` and `EXID` are getting inserted in this table.

I have created another table `VK_MODIFY` with below columns:

```
OID
EXID
FILENAME
FIRST_INSERT_DATE 
LATEST_MODIFY_DATE
```

Now i want to write sql statment i am not sure if `Merge` sql statment works with the below conditions:

If the combination of columns values `OID, EXID` does not yet exist in the table then :

```
- Insert a new row
- Set FIRST_INSERT_DATE = LATEST_MODIFY_DATE = now()
- Write the name of the file to FILENAME
```

If the combination of columns value `OID, EXID` already exists in the table then:

```
- set LATEST_MODIFY_DATE = now()
- append the name of the file to FILENAME (prepend a comma – no space)
```

I can then simply run this query once in a day to update my `VK_MODIFY` table. I am not sure how to write this sql statment and whether its possible to using oracle sql statement.

`DDL` for `VK_MODIFY` table which has same data type as `VK_ORDER` table.

```
CREATE TABLE
    VK_MODIFY
    (
     FIRST_INSERT_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,  
     LATEST_MODIFY_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL, 
     FILENAME VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
     OID INTEGER,
     EXID VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MERGE` query as follows:

```
MERGE INTO VK_MODIFY T
USING (SELECT * FROM VK_ORDER) S
   ON (T.OID = S.OID AND (T.EXID = S.EXID OR (T.EXID IS NULL AND S.EXID IS NULL)))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET T.FILENAME = S.FILENAME || ',' || T.FILENAME,
              T.LATEST_MODIFY_DATE = SYSDATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(OID, EXID, FILENAME, FIRST_INSERT_DATE, LATEST_MODIFY_DATE) 
     VALUES (S.OID, S.EXID, S.FILENAME, SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
```

Comment: actually i am getting error ORA-01722: invalid number but i have created the columns data type in VK_MODIFY  table same as VK_ORDER

Comment: Is it because of date datatype ? FIRST_INSERT_DATE and LATEST_MODIFY_DATE data type are TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL, FILENAME datatype VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, OID integer and EXID VARCHAR2(100)

Comment: See the updated answer. In `INSERT` added column names

Comment: yes the query is running now but the problem is i see OID and EXID are duplicated in the table...we can ignore the condition 'append the name of the file to FILENAME' because the length of the column can exceed in future but the table should not have redundant combination of OID and EXID...there are redundant values where EXID are null for same OID and it should also check this condition

Comment: Ok, That is taken care in the updated answer. Please check now!!

Comment: I really dont understand still why its inserting duplicate data...and also i have created non unique index on EXID and OID on table VK_MODIFY but its taking too much time to execute the merge statement. The  VK_ORDER table has 662456 rows.

Comment: What is the meaning of duplicate in your case? and yes, 662456 rows is very less for otacle

Comment: For example after merge execution if i search for OID 563162, it has multiple EXID 21083448, 21083448, 21083448 ... Normally there should be only one EXID 21083448 for OID 563162

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216052/discussion-between-tejash-and-symonds).

Comment: still i am facing same duplicate data issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming oid and exid are both not null,

```
merge into vk_modify M
```

using (select * from vk_order) O
on ((M.OID,M.EXID) = (O.OID,O.EXID))
when matched then update
  set M.filename=M.filename||','||O.filename,
  latest_modify_date=sysdate
when not matched then insert (oid,exid,filename,first_insert_date,latest_modify_date)
values (O.oid,O.exid,O.filename,sysdate,sysdate);